# Plot categorical variable

Tags: r, plot

I am new in R, and I follow the instruction slides to plot:

[image]

The `survey[["Program"]]` is the categorical data column from the data frame.

```
> survey[["Program"]]  # returns the Program column as a vector
 [1] "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "Other" "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "Other" "PPM"   "Other" "MISM"  "PPM"   "MISM" 
[14] "Other" "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "Other" "PPM"   "MISM"  "PPM"   "PPM"   "PPM"   "MISM" 
[27] "PPM"   "Other" "Other" "PPM"   "Other"
```

However, when I implement `plot(survey[["Program"]])`, I get the error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I don't know why I cannot get the same result as I show in the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plot command only works on a `factor` column. (Well, it works on a lot of things, but the confusion here is because of variable not being a factor.) Compare e.g.

```
plot(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'))
```

> ```
> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
> 2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> ```

with

```
plot(factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c')))
```

[image]

You can check the classes of your columns by calling `str(survey)`. You may have read in the data in a different way than those slides assumed.

You can either use

```
plot(factor(survey[["Program"]]))
```

Or perhaps

```
barplot(table(survey[["Program"]]))
```

to get the same result.